# How to get ParseObject's createdAt date as String?

Tags: android, parse-platform, date-format

How do I get the date from the `ParseObject`'s `createdAt` column and convert it to a `String` in the `DD-MM-YYYY` format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get the date from Parse like this:

```
Date date = object.getCreatedAt();
```

And then in the adapter or wherever you want:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String reportDate = df.format(date);
```

Comment: thank you very much , this answer helped me a lot, I just changed the first line a bit so that it works! thanks again ;)